# How to replace "vendor" string with "Artist" everywhere in dokan lite plugin?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, dokan

I want to replace "vendor" string present in dokan plugin to "Artist" string everywhere. I searched for the solution but couldn't found it anywhere. Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

If you change from the code then you have to modify the entire Dokan. I have an alternate solution for you which you can apply via Translation and I call it Translation Method- https://nayemdevs.com/translation-method-to-change-string-without-doing-any-code/

I hope this will make the job easier for you.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Use Dokan Api . You can customize it anyway you want